# After posting a webform, how do I get the values from the result page?

Tags: python, http, post, python-requests

I'm using requests (as adviced by Daniel Roseman) to post on a webform:

```
url = "http://mascot.proteomics.dundee.ac.uk/cgi/search_form.pl?FORMVER=2&SEARCH=MIS"
data = {'SEARCH':'MIS'}
files = {'JG-C1-1A.mgf' : open('/homes/ndeklein/Cantrell/JG-C1-1.mgf','rb')}    print
```

when I print `r.ok` and `r.request` I get 200 ok, so the POST worked. When I print the r.content I don't get the result page but html of the page where the form is submitted. When I remove the `{'SEARCH':'MIS'}` from data `r.content` returns a html error page that the search type is missing, so I know that if something is wrong in the post I get an error.

So how can I get the result page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to use `httplib`, honestly. It's a low-level interface and is unnecessarily complex for what you want to do. At the very least, use `urllib2`, which will follow any redirects. But probably your best bet is to use the [third-party `requests` module](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) which makes all this a ton easier.

Comment: All the questions I could find on uploading files with multipart/form data had as answers using http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/fa though, which uses httplib. Do you know where I can find a mulipart/form data using urllib? And I'm using python 2.6 AFAIK requests is for python 3 (they dropped python 2.5 support)

Comment: Er, dropping Python 2.5 doesn't mean it doesn't work in 2.6, and [it clearly does](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/#python-3-support). And [here's](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) the documentation for multipart files.

Comment: You're right, thanks for that. But I still have the same problem that I don't get the result page.